# Adding multi language option to a symfony 3 project

Tags: php, symfony, multilingual

Reading the documentation of symfony 3, I got very confused, and I'm not sure if I'm doing everything right. This is how one of my normal controller looked at the start:

```
class IndexController extends Controller

    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="index")
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            $articles = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

            return $this->render("index.html.twig", array(
                'articles' => $articles
            ));
        }
    }
```

I wanted to add option for multy language. Before symfony I saw doing this with simple saving in session the language, and a button for changing it. In symfony I added a **translations** folder, and a file for each language.

```
//messages.en.yml
    base.menu.1: Home
    base.menu.2: Products
    base.menu.3: Brands

//messages.bg.yml
    base.menu.1: Начало
    base.menu.2: Продукти
    base.menu.3: Марки
```

After this I saw in some titorial that I can add my **_locale**, in my route like this:
*@Route("{_locale}/", name="index")*
And this actually worked. My I could of change my home page's language by going in bg/, or en/.
But the locale variabe wasn't saved anywhere. If I went to other page, it doesn't know what language was setted up before. So I read more, and was I can fix this, by saving all of my routes in *routing.yml* like this:

```
index:
    path:     /{_locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Index:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'
```

and then set up my config:

```
parameters:
    locale: bg
    app.locales: bg|en

framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

All this is working, except I have to move my routing from their controllers to *routing.yml*. I want to ask if this is the right method, to do all of this, because I'm not sure, the documentation isn't 100% clear (most likely I just cant understand it), and can't find any good titorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the '[make locale sticky](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html)' method, as stated above,

then set the locale using

```
$request->setLocale($locale);
$request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);

//now redirect as the locale change will take affect on the next pageload
```

(set both, and redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Whether by Annotation or by configuration in YAML, the end result is the same. You'll fall into a debate of for/against annotations if you're not careful though, and I'll just go ahead and say that I do not recommend them personally. Your `routing.yml` approach is the approach I would recommend, and should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you've read Symfony's post on [How to Work with the User's Locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html) and what you're looking for is [Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html).

> Symfony stores the locale setting in the Request, which means that this setting is not automtically saved ("sticky") across requests. But, you can store the locale in the session, so that it's used on subsequent requests.

Comment: So I added the kernel event subscriber and I'm not touching the url, but it seem that I can only change the language from: public function __construct($defaultLocale = '<language>') I tryed using $request->setLocale('bg'); in my controller, just to test, and it does actually change the locale, I can see this by $request->getLocale();, but it does not change the language of the page. I think I'm doing it too late and its already set. Or I'm doing it incorrectly. What is the right way to change the lang from here?